# How to provide shellscript input from java

Tags: java, shell, jsp, jsch

I have created the shell script to add two numbers. I want to execute that shell script from java. Can you please help me on this.

```
first_num=0
second_num=0
echo -n "Enter the first number-->"
read first_num
echo -n "Enter the second number-->"
read second_num
echo "first number + second number = $ (( first_num + second_num ))"
```

And I need a piece of code based on the "jsch" library

Comment: Reposted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605233/how-to-pass-the-input-value-to-shell-script-using-java

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by getting the runtime, as next

```
        Process p = null;
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime ();
        String rutaFinal=path+carpeta+"/";
        System.out.println("** Executing command *****");
        p = rt.exec("chmod x process.sh");
        p = rt.exec ("sh process.sh");
        p.waitFor();
```

Also you can execute commands one by one, hope this help!!!