# How to pass the input value to shell script using java

Tags: java, jsch

I have created the shell script to add two numbers. I want to execute that shell script from java and I am using Jsch library. Can you please help me on this.

```
first_num=0
second_num=0
echo -n "Enter the first number-->"
read first_num
echo -n "Enter the second number-->"
read second_num
echo "first number + second number = $ (( first_num + second_num ))"
```

Yes. I have checked examples in "Jsch" sites, But i am not able to enter the input to shell script.

I tried as you said. Please see the following piece of code

```
String command = "bash /home/opt/addtwonumber.sh 1 2"
```

And I changed the shell script mentioned below

```
$first_num
$second_num
echo "first number + second number = $ (( first_num + second_num ))"
```

But it doesn't work. i am getting the results like

```
first_number + second_number  = 0
```

Comment: Jsch is for accessing a remote machine. Is your script on a different machine? Have you looked at the examples in the Jsch web sites? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post you java code which you are using to execute the script

Answer (score 0):

from the examples :

```
    String user = "USERNAME";
    host = "HOSTNAME";

    UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
    session.setUserInfo(ui);
    session.connect();

    Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    String command = "YOUR_SCRIPTFILE_HERE PARAMETER_ONE PARAMETER_TWO";
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

    channel.setInputStream(null);

    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

    channel.connect();

    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0)
                break;
            System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
        }
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            if (in.available() > 0)
                continue;
            System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
```

Mind you : **never** use `while(true)` in any production-ready code, thats just ... bad code and it will break / generate deadlocks at some point, no matter how many exceptions you catch, no matter how often you insert statements like `break` - it will happen.

So all you need to do is place your parameters immediately after your scriptfile and that should be about it - but that only works with commandline parameters, AFAIK it isnt easily possible to input parameters during script runtime - `read` will not work for you as your script apparently isnt local. You cant use scripts which require local input, you need to switch to commandline parameters - namely `$1`, `$2` and so on.

Heres the interface for `MyUserInfo` : [*click](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html)